# Nativescript fingerprint auth plugin - can't log anything after verifyFingerprint promise

Tags: android, angular, types, nativescript, fingerprint

My goal is to add a biometric option to my nativescript app.
The user gets a prompt in which i'm waiting for his authentication.
if authenticated  - I want to console.log("Great"). and if not log "Problem".

I'm building it using Angular + Nativescript, so I registered Fingerprint as as provider, imported it and on constructor decalred:

```
constructor(private fingerprintAuth: FingerprintAuth);
```

And for the verifyFingerPrint, when page loads I call:

```
this.fingerprintAuth.available()
                .then((result: BiometricIDAvailableResult) => {
                    console.log(`Biometric ID available? ${result.any}`);
                    if(result.any) {
                        if(result.face) {
                            console.log("HANDLE FACE WILL BE HERE SOON!");
                        }

                        if(result.touch) {
                            console.log("If not face, then touch id. Let's try it.");

                            this.fingerprintAuth.verifyFingerprint(
                                {
                                    title: "Biometric Verification",
                                    message: "Let's just make sure it's you..."
                                })
                                .then((data) => console.log("Authenticated, contacting server now...", data))
                                .catch((e) => console.log("Problem occured while authenticated.", e))
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("No Biometric Option is available, try adding one.");
                    }
                });
    }
```

**The problem is, I am getting the fingerprint prompt as expected, but after a good or bad verification I never get the console.log part. .then / .catch - both won't log anything**

And i'm not getting any errors..

I'm using sidekick, 
local build on a Pixel 3 XL API 28 Emulator,
Plugin name:**nativescript-fingerprint-auth**
Nativescript + Angular Project

What could be the problem..?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of {N} runtime and plugin you are using?

Comment: I'm using NativeScript 6.5 and fingerprint-auth 7.0.2

Comment: Can you try logging or placing a debugger at [this line](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-fingerprint-auth/blob/master/src/fingerprint-auth.android.ts#L215), check what's the value of `tryEncryptResult`. You can direct open the JS file from node modules and do the changes, CLI should pick it up.

Comment: Yeah ok so, I consoled it and it returned as undefined.
But I was wrong, I'm not using it when pages load.
If i'm using it when page loads it works fine,
But i'm using a barcode scanner, so after a barcode has been scanned, I ask the user to auth using it. and then - nothing happens.
Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: hmm.. fixed the problem... not sure how or if it's the best way. 
I added setTimeout of 100ms before calling the touch id verification method...